# Pivot_longer two colums mixing character and numeric in R

Tags: r

I need to pivot to longer multiple colums whose names start with "d" and "v". They are set in pairs for every day of the month. For example, for January 1st. I have a d01 and a v01 column. The columns idenfify with "v" are character class, while the columns identify with "d" are numeric values.

So far I manage to produce the desired result with the following commands:

```
tbl.aqi_values <- tbl.aqi %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('d'), names_to = 'dia', values_to = "valor") %>%
  select(provincia, municipio, estacion, magnitud, punto_muestreo, ano, mes, dia, valor)%>%
  mutate(dia = as.numeric(str_remove(dia, 'd')))
```

```
tbl.aqi_check <- 
  tbl.aqi %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('v'), names_to = "dia", values_to = "check") %>%
  select(provincia, municipio, estacion, magnitud, punto_muestreo, ano, mes, dia, check) %>%
  mutate(dia = as.numeric(str_remove(dia, 'v')))
```

```
tbl.aqi = left_join(tbl.aqi_values, tbl.aqi_check, by = c('provincia', 'municipio', 'estacion', 'magnitud', 'punto_muestreo', 'ano', 'mes', 'dia'))
```

I would like to now if there is a simpler way to do this.

This is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(provincia = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), municipio = c(79L, 
79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L), estacion = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), magnitud = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), punto_muestreo = c("28079004_1_38", 
"28079004_1_38", "28079004_1_38", "28079004_1_38", "28079004_1_38", 
"28079004_1_38"), ano = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L), mes = 1:6, d01 = c(17, 40, 19, 14, 10, 13), v01 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d02 = c(15, 42, 18, 17, 11, 10), v02 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d03 = c(15, 38, 13, 13, 16, 12), v03 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d04 = c(15, 29, 11, 10, 18, 11), v04 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d05 = c(16, 18, 15, 9, 15, 12), v05 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d06 = c(20, 23, 23, 17, 13, 11), v06 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d07 = c(25, 16, 15, 11, 13, 12), v07 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d08 = c(30, 17, 12, 10, 17, 14), v08 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d09 = c(32, 17, 11, 16, 13, 8), v09 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d10 = c(33, 21, 10, 17, 13, 7), v10 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d11 = c(21, 36, 13, 12, 18, 10), v11 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d12 = c(36, 40, 20, 8, 14, 10), v12 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d13 = c(39, 37, 16, 8, 8, 12), v13 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d14 = c(34, 26, 28, 9, 9, 11), v14 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d15 = c(23, 23, 25, 14, 8, 9), v15 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d16 = c(16, 27, 17, 18, 9, 7), v16 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d17 = c(16, 33, 12, 12, 9, 9), v17 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d18 = c(17, 26, 11, 13, 9, 8), v18 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d19 = c(27, 26, 14, 17, 9, 17), v19 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d20 = c(40, 40, 20, 13, 8, 17), v20 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d21 = c(32, 42, 14, 15, 9, 19), v21 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d22 = c(29, 42, 19, 16, 9, 18), v22 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d23 = c(17, 42, 30, 10, 11, 17), v23 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d24 = c(17, 27, 14, 9, 11, 19), v24 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d25 = c(14, 21, 11, 11, 13, 13), v25 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d26 = c(12, 22, 14, 12, 13, 11), v26 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d27 = c(19, 20, 14, 12, 11, 9), v27 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d28 = c(17, 22, 15, 13, 15, 11), v28 = c("V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d29 = c(35, 0, 17, 15, 16, 18), v29 = c("V", 
"N", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d30 = c(40, 0, 20, 14, 15, 19), v30 = c("V", 
"N", "V", "V", "V", "V"), d31 = c(53, 0, 19, 0, 18, 0), v31 = c("V", 
"N", "V", "N", "V", "N")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you provide  `dput(head(tbl.aqi))` to facilitate testing?

Comment: It is better to show a small reproducible example with `dput`.  Perhaps `tbl.aqi %>% pivot_longer(cols = matches('^[dv]\\d+$'), names_to = c(".value", "grp"), names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])")`

Comment: Sure. I edited my initial question. Thanks for your help